# json cache pattern architecture

Tags: c#, asp.net, json

I have an object model called MyObject that I'm serializing to a json string and I'm storing that string in the DB. I want to send several of these objects to the page.

When the objects come out of the DB, they're put into a list of objects called JsonCache like this:

```
    public class JsonCache
    {
      public int ObjectID {get;set;}
      public byte ObjectStatus {get;set;}
      public string MyObjectInJsonFormat {get;set;}
    }

List<JsonCache> MyListOfMyObjects = new List<JsonCache>();
```

MyObjectInJsonFormat is the string that contains all the properties of MyObject (9 lists of nested objects.)
Before sending this list to the page, I serialize it with a simple serializer like this:

```
JavaScriptSerializer ObjectSerializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
string LeadsToPage = ObjectSerializer.Serialize(MyListOfObjects);
```

and then I put this string in an aspx literal that's inside a div called MyDiv.

In the client page, I write this javascript:

```
var ObjectsFromServer = $('#MyDiv').html();
ObjectsInJson = eval(ObjectsFromServer);
```

The problem is that ObjectsInJson is an array that contains the JsonCache object model, with the string ObjectInJsonFormat. Of course, I could de a recursive eval but that's not what I want. What I'm looking to do is have ObjectInJson be an array of MyObject.

What do I need to change to make this work?

Thanks for your suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a custom serializer like [JavaScriptConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptconverter.aspx) for JsonCache and do something special for MyObjectInJsonFormat.